# Accessing Array Length comes back as Zero

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I have an array in ActionScript 3 that is formatted as follows:

```
var _arrayList = new Array;
_arrayList["item1"] = true;
_arrayList["item2"] = 56;
_arrayList["item3"] = "john doe";
_arrayList["item4"] = -56.8;
```

and I'm attempting to pull the "_arrayList.Length" but it comes back 0... why?

Comment: Read this to understand why [**fundamentals of Arrays**](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/vectors-and-bytearrays.html) and also this [**Associative arrays**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7eea.html). Essentially this is the read up to what Andrey Popov said..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the way you do it makes the array "associative". In Action Script, every class is a basic Object, with dynamic properties. And array does both - containing indexed elements, and having a dynamic properties.

Here's an example of a regular array:

```
var array:Array = new Array();
array.push(value); // equal to array[0] = value;
array.push(56); // equal to array[1] = value;

array[20] = 'test'; // will put 20th element to be 'test'
```

If you use this approach, the `length` of the array will not be `0`. And so you can use a `for` loop:

```
var total:uint = array.length;
for (var i:uint = 0; i < total; i++) {
    trace (array[i]);
}
```

But when the keys are not numeric, you are actually setting "properties" to the array and thus the length is `0`. Again, you can loop through them, but with `for-in`:

```
for (var key:String in array) {
    trace (array[key]);
}
```

Here the keys won't be `0, 1, 2, 3` and so on, but instead will be `item1, item2, item3`. (keep in mind that the order is not preserved!)

So the basic conclusion is that if you use non-numeric keys, then use an Object instead. Array is for numeric indexed collections.

Comment: I appreciate this... i'll look into objects